# What is the easiest, most straight-forward way to prove this about minimum-phase filters?

Tags: hilbert-transform, causality, minimum-phase

Using the *"unitary"* or *"ordinary frequency"* or *"Hz"* convention for the continuous Fourier Transform:

$$ \begin{align}
X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\{x(t)\} &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \, e^{-j 2 \pi f t} \, dt \\
\\
x(t) = \mathscr{F}^{-1}\{X(f)\} &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(f) \, e^{j 2 \pi f t} \, df \\
\end{align} $$

So we learn that the Hilbert transform maps a signal or function in the time domain to another in the same domain:

$$ \begin{align}
\hat{x}(t) \triangleq \mathscr{H}\{x(t)\} &= \frac{1}{\pi t} \circledast x(t) \\
\\
&= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi u} \, x(t-u) \, du \\
\\
&= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (t-u)} \, x(u) \, du \\
\end{align} $$

and the Hilbert transformer is LTI, so we know that $ \hat{x}(t-\tau) = \mathscr{H}\{x(t-\tau)\}$ .  And, even though LTI, we know that a Hilbert transformer is not causal (but, given enough delay, we can realize an approximation to a Hilbert transformer as well, to a given non-zero error, as we want).

And we know that this LTI Hilbert transformer has frequency response

$$ \begin{align}
\hat{X}(f) & \triangleq \mathscr{F}\{\hat{x}(t)\} \\
\\
           & = -j \, \operatorname{sgn}(f) X(f) \\
\\
           & = \begin{cases} e^{-j \pi/2} \, X(f) \qquad & f>0 \\
                             0                    \qquad & f=0 \\
                             e^{+j \pi/2} \, X(f) \qquad & f<0 \\ \end{cases} \\
\end{align} $$

where, of course, $X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\{x(t)\}$ .  So all positive frequency components are shifted in phase by -90° and all negative frequency components are phase shifted by +90°.  None of the amplitudes are affected except for DC, which is wiped out.  That's fundamentally what a Hilbert transformer does.

From this we know about analytic signals:

$$\begin{align}
x_\text{a}(t) & \triangleq x(t) + j\hat{x}(t) \\
\\
X_\text{a}(f) & = X(f) + j\hat{X}(f) \\
              & = X(f) + j( -j \, \operatorname{sgn}(f) X(f) ) \\
              & = (1 +  \operatorname{sgn}(f)) \, X(f) \\
\\
              & = \begin{cases} 2 X(f) \qquad & f>0 \\
                             X(f)      \qquad & f=0 \\
                             0         \qquad & f<0 \\ \end{cases} \\
\end{align}$$

So, if we have a complex-valued time-domain signal, $x_\text{a}(t)$ in which the real and imaginary parts of this signal form a Hilbert-transform pair, then in the frequency domain, all negative frequency components have zero-amplitude.  Because of the symmetrical nature of the Fourier transform, we have **duality** and can reverse the roles of time $t$ and frequency $f$.  This means, *if we have a complex-valued* frequency-domain spectrum, $X(f)$ *in which the real and imaginary parts of this* spectrum *form a Hilbert-transform pair, then in the* time domain, *all negative* time *components have zero-amplitude*.

Stated again, but substituting impulse response $h(t)$ for $x(t)$, and frequency response $H(f)$ for $X(f)$, we know

$$ \Im m \{h(t)\} = \mathscr{H}\big\{\Re e\{h(t)\}\big\} \iff H(f) = 0 \quad \forall f<0 $$

and similarly

$$ \Im m \{H(f)\} = -\mathscr{H}\big\{\Re e\{H(f)\}\big\} \iff h(t) = 0 \quad \forall t<0 $$

where $H(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\{h(t)\}$

An LTI system described by impulse response $h(t)$ that is zero for all $t$ that is negative, is what we call a "**causal system**", because the impulse response does not respond to the driving impulse until that driving impulse occurs in time.  So for every realizable, real-time LTI system (which must be causal), the real and imaginary parts of the frequency response are a Hilbert pair in the frequency domain.  None of this is particularly surprizing or special.

So (as Matt anticipated) there is something more about relating the real and imaginary parts of *something* regarding LTI systems that **is** a bit surprizing (or, at least, is not trivial).  We have **two** definitions or descriptions of LTI systems or LTI filters that are in this class called "**minimum-phase filters**":

1. LTI filters with rational transfer functions (of which the numerator and denominator can be factored resulting in roots that are called zeros and poles, respectively) in which **both** poles and zeros lie in the left-half plane:

$$ H\left( \frac{s}{j 2 \pi} \right) = A \frac{(s-q_1)(s-q_2)...(s-q_M)}{(s-p_1)(s-p_2)...(s-p_N)} \qquad \qquad M \le N $$

Required for stability: $ \Re e\{p_n\} < 0 $ for all $1 \le n \le N$

Required for minimum phase: $ \Re e\{q_m\} < 0 $ for all $1 \le m \le M$

These filters are called *"minimum phase"* because for any zero $q_m$ in the left half-plane, an **All-pass filter** having a pole at precisely the same location will cancel that zero and will reflect it to the right half-plane:

$$ H_\text{AP}\left( \frac{s}{j 2 \pi} \right) = \frac{s+q_m}{s-q_m} $$

This all-pass filter has frequency response with magnitude of exactly 0 dB for all frequencies:

$$ |H_\text{AP}(f)| = 1 \qquad \qquad \forall f $$

but the phase angle is **not** zero, this APF adds (negative) phase shift:

$$ \arg \{ H_\text{AP}(f) \} = -2 \arctan\left(\frac{2 \pi f - \Im m \{q_m\}}{-\Re e\{q_m\}}\right) $$

The resulting cascaded filter $H\left( \frac{s}{j 2 \pi} \right) \cdot H_\text{AP}\left( \frac{s}{j 2 \pi} \right)$ with the zero $q_m$ reflected to the right half-plane has the same magnitude as the original filter (having all zeros in the left half-plane), but has more (negative) phase shift.  More phase delay and more group delay.  The *"minimum-phase"* filter is the only filter having exactly the same magnitude response that has less (negative) phase shift than any of the clones with APFs reflecting zeros to the right half-plane.

A *"Maximum-phase"* filter is one where **all** of the zeros live in the right half-plane or $\Re e\{ q_m \} \ge 0$ .

So the second definition of a minimum-phase filter specifies exactly how this minimum-phase response is related to the magnitude response:

2. An LTI system or filter

$$ H(f) = |H(f)| e^{j \arg\{H(f)\}} = |H(f)| e^{j \phi(f)} $$

is minimum phase if and only if the natural phase response, in radians, is the negative of the Hilbert transform of the natural logarithm of the magnitude response:

$$ \phi(f) \triangleq \arg\{ H(f) \} = -\mathscr{H}\big\{ \ln( |H(f)| ) \big\} $$

since

$$\begin{align}
 H(f) & = |H(f)| e^{j \phi(f)} \\
  & = e^{\ln(|H(f)|)} e^{j \phi(f)} \\
  & = e^{\ln(|H(f)|) + j \phi(f)} \\
  & = e^{\ln(H(f))} \\
\end{align}$$

this is relating the real and imaginary parts of the complex natural $\log()$ of the frequency response.  Say we can construct a hypothetical LTI filter, $G(f)$ with complex frequency response equal to that complex logarithm

$$\begin{align}
 G(f) & = \ln(H(f)) \\
  & = \ln(|H(f)|) + j \phi(f) \\
  & = \Re e\{G(f)\} + j \Im m \{G(f)\} \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
 \Im m \{G(f)\} & = \phi(f) = -\mathscr{H}\big\{ \ln( |H(f)| ) \big\} \\
             & = -\mathscr{H}\big\{ \Re e\{G(f)\} \big\} \\
\end{align}$$

then the impulse response corresponding to $G(f)$ would be causal:

$$ \mathscr{F}^{-1}\{ G(f) \} = g(t) = 0 \qquad \qquad \forall t<0 $$

The purpose of this question is to resolve the two definitions of a minimum-phase filter.  If, given the first definition, I don't see any direct reason why the hypothetical $G(f) = \ln(H(f))$ should have a causal impulse response $g(t)$.

The only way to resolve the two definitions directly is to consider:

$$ H(f) = A \frac{(j2\pi f-q_1)(j2\pi f-q_2)...(j2\pi f-q_M)}{(j2\pi f-p_1)(j2\pi f-p_2)...(j2\pi f-p_N)}$$

(assume for the moment that $A>0$)

$$ \ln(|H(f)|) = \ln(A) + \sum_{m=1}^{M} \ln(|j2\pi f-q_m|) - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \ln(|j2\pi f-p_n|) $$

$$ \phi(f) \triangleq \arg\{H(f)\} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \arg\{j2\pi f-q_m\} - \sum_{n=1}^{N} \arg\{j2\pi f-p_n\} $$

We know that the Hilbert transform of a constant function is zero, so

$$ \mathscr{H}\big\{ \ln(A) \big\} = 0 $$

then **if** we can prove that each remaining corresponding terms of the summations in $\ln(|H(f)|)$ and $\arg\{H(f)\}$ are Hilbert pairs,  that is, if we can show

$$ \arg\{j2\pi f-q_m\} = -\mathscr{H}\big\{ \ln(|j2\pi f-q_m|) \big\} \qquad 1 \le m \le M $$

and

$$ \arg\{j2\pi f-p_n\} = -\mathscr{H}\big\{ \ln(|j2\pi f-p_n|) \big\} \qquad 1 \le n \le N $$

given that $\Re e\{q_m\} < 0$ and $\Re e\{p_n\} < 0$,

then we can show that

$$ \phi(f) \triangleq \arg\{ H(f) \} = -\mathscr{H}\big\{ \ln( |H(f)| ) \big\} $$

We don't have to worry much about phase wrapping when considering a single first-order term.  Since the form is the same for both zeros and poles, considering just a single zero

$$\begin{align}
 \arg\{j2\pi f - q_m\} & = \arg\{j2\pi f - (\Re e\{q_m\} + j \Im m \{q_m\})\} \\
           & = \arg\{-\Re e\{q_m\} + j(2\pi f - \Im m \{q_m\})\} \\
           & = \arctan\left(\frac{2\pi f - \Im m \{q_m\}}{-\Re e\{q_m\}}\right) \\
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
 \ln(|j2\pi f-q_m|) & = \ln(|j2\pi f - (\Re e\{q_m\} + j \Im m \{q_m\})|) \\
           & = \ln(|-\Re e\{q_m\} + j(2\pi f - \Im m \{q_m\})|) \\
           & = \ln\left( \sqrt{(-\Re e\{q_m\})^2 + (2\pi f - \Im m \{q_m\})^2} \ \right) \\
           & = \tfrac12 \ln\big( (-\Re e\{q_m\})^2 + (2\pi f - \Im m \{q_m\})^2 \big) \\
\end{align}$$

So now it becomes a task to show that

$$ \arctan\left(\frac{2\pi f - \Im m \{q_m\}}{-\Re e\{q_m\}}\right) = -\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \ln\big((-\Re e\{q_m\})^2 + (2\pi f - \Im m \{q_m\})^2 \big) \Big\} $$

Now remember that, in the time domain, the Hilbert transformer is LTI, so we know that $\hat{x}(t-\tau) = \mathscr{H}\{x(t-\tau)\}$ and it doesn't matter what $\tau$ is, it's just an offset to time $t$ in both input and output to the Hilbert transformer.

Here, in the frequency domain, the offset to frequency $f$ is $\frac{\Im m \{q_m\}}{2 \pi}$, so without loss of generality, we can eliminate $\Im m \{q_m\}$ from both sides:

$$ \arctan\left(\frac{2\pi f}{-\Re e\{q_m\}}\right) = -\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \ln\big((-\Re e\{q_m\})^2 + (2\pi f)^2 \big) \Big\} $$

This breaks the problem down to a **single** real pole and real zero, both in the left half-plane.  Now we can normalize out $-\Re e\{q_m\}$ and the $2 \pi$ with the substitution:

$$ \omega \triangleq \frac{2\pi f}{-\Re e\{q_m\}} $$

resulting in

$$\begin{align}
 \arctan(\omega) &= -\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \ln\big((-\Re e\{q_m\})^2 + (\omega \cdot (-\Re e\{q_m\}))^2 \big) \Big\} \\
&= -\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \ln\big((-\Re e\{q_m\})^2 \cdot (1 + \omega^2) \big) \Big\} \\
&= -\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \ln(-\Re e\{q_m\}) + \tfrac12 \ln(1 + \omega^2) \Big\} \\
&= -\mathscr{H}\Big\{ \tfrac12 \ln(1 + \omega^2) \Big\} \\
\end{align}$$

That last term $\ln(-\Re e\{q_m\})$ is eliminated because the Hilbert transform of a constant is zero.

So now, **the bottom line**, to prove the equivalence of the two definitions of what a minimum-phase filter is, we *"simply"* need to prove the identity above (or below).

Can someone, without using Contour Integration or Residue Theory or results from complex variable analysis, prove this fact? :

$$\begin{align}
 \arctan(\omega) &= -\tfrac12 \mathscr{H}\big\{ \ln(1 + \omega^2) \big\} \\
\\ 
  &= -\tfrac12 \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi u} \, \ln(1 + (\omega-u)^2) \, du \\
\\
  &= -\tfrac12 \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi (\omega-u)} \, \ln(1 + u^2) \, du \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I guess this is going to be about the Hilbert transform relationship between log magnitude and phase of a minimum phase system ...?

Comment: i'm getting there, @MattL. it's going to be about reconciling the two different definitions of a minimum-phase filter.  and we hadn't yet gotten to the second definition (that you allude to).

Comment: Wow @robertbristow-johnson! That last line and equation may be good to post in the mathematics site as well (with no need of the background there I don't think, only the definition of $\mathscr{H}$)

Comment: something like that is my plan, @DanBoschen .  just want to throw it out here first.  maybe let Olli or MattL. take a whack at it.  (i have an approach, and it is showing the derivatives of the two functions make a Hilbert pair.)

Comment: so @DanBoschen, i have [done exactly as you suggested](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199416/can-someone-prove-this-integral-regarding-the-hilbert-transform).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Awesome, I just upvoted it and looking forward to the solution. I still think you are right that Olli or MattL will solve it first, but we'll see!

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson here is an interesting observation in case this shortens the path to a simple explanation or ideally intuitive insight: I notice that if I raise any real magnitude to the power j, the angle also is the natural log of that magnitude (coincidence?) I have not had the time thoroughly think this through with relation to the question but wanted to throw that out there: for example $10^j = e^{j ln(10)}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hilbert transform $\mathcal{H}\left\{f(\omega)\right\}$ with

$$f(\omega)=-\frac12\log(1+\omega^2)\tag{1}$$

can be calculated in the following way. First, note that

$$\frac{df(\omega)}{d\omega}=-\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}\tag{2}$$

From [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Table_of_selected_Hilbert_transforms) we know that

$$\mathcal{H}\left\{\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}\right\}=\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}\tag{3}$$

We also [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Inverse_transform) that

$$\mathcal{H}\{\mathcal{H}\{f\}\}=-f\tag{4}$$

Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get

$$\mathcal{H}\left\{\frac{\omega}{1+\omega^2}\right\}=\mathcal{H}\left\{\mathcal{H}\left\{\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}\right\}\right\}=-\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}\tag{5}$$

So, using $(2)$,

$$\mathcal{H}\left\{\frac{df(\omega)}{d\omega}\right\}=\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}\tag{6}$$

Now we also [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Differentiation) that the Hilbert transform operator and the differentiation operator commute:

$$\mathcal{H}\left\{\frac{df(\omega)}{d\omega}\right\}=\frac{d}{d\omega}\mathcal{H}\{f(\omega)\}\tag{7}$$

which yields

$$\frac{d}{d\omega}\mathcal{H}\{f(\omega)\}=\frac{1}{1+\omega^2}\tag{8}$$

Integrating $(8)$ finally gives

$$\mathcal{H}\{f(\omega)\}=\arctan(\omega)\tag{9}$$

---

Note that this result can also be obtained using Mathematica (which I don't have available). According to [this thread](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/452534?p_p_auth=ql6vcWRY), the command

```
Integrate[-1/2*Log[1 + (\[Tau]*\[Nu])^2]/(\[Nu] - \[Omega]), {\[Nu], -Infinity, Infinity},
 PrincipalValue -> True, Assumptions -> \[Tau] >0 && \[Omega] >0, GenerateConditions -> False]/Pi
```

gives

`-ArcTan[\[Tau] \[Omega]]`

The negative sign comes from the different definition of the Hilbert transform, as can be seen in the denominator of the integral in the Mathematica command.

---

I would like to add that the causality of the inverse Fourier transform of $\log H(j\omega)$, i.e., the causality of the complex [cepstrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cepstrum) for a minimum-phase system $H(j\omega)$ can also be understood intuitively. Note that any zero of $H(s)$ in the right half-plane causes a singularity in $\log H(s)$ in the right half-plane, and consequently, the corresponding inverse Fourier transform must be two-sided because the region of convergence is a strip including the imaginary axis. Only if there are no zeros in the right half-plane (i.e., the system is minimum-phase) will $\log H(s)$ have all its singularities in the left half-plane, and the inverse transform yields a right-sided causal function.

---

From $(4)$ we can see another nice property of the Hilbert transform, namely that the inverse transform is simply given by the (forward) transform with a negative sign:

$$\mathcal{H}^{-1}\{f\}=-\mathcal{H}\{f\}\tag{10}$$

That means that for every Hilbert transform pair that we find, we get another one for free:

$$\mathcal{H}\{f\}=g\Longrightarrow\mathcal{H}\{g\}=-f\tag{11}$$

Applying $(11)$ to $(9)$ we find

$$\mathcal{H}\{\arctan(\omega)\}=-f(\omega)=\frac12\log(1+\omega^2)\tag{12}$$

Comment: that negative sign (with *Mathematica*) is still bothersome to me, Matt.  just screw the definition of the Hilbert transform, it's an integral.  *Mathematica* does not toss in a spurious sign change with their definition of an indefinite integral with Cauchy p.v.,

Comment: oh, it's the reversal of order of $\nu$ and $\omega$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yes, just look at the denominator, it's $\nu-\Omega$ and we're integrating over $\nu$.

Comment: i am not on-board with the bottom causality argument.  just because $H(s)$ is rational, doesn't mean that $\log(H(s))$ is.  even so, putting the singularities of $\log(H(s))$ all into the left half-plane doesn't provide for causality, but provides for stability.  not really the same thing.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: $\log H(s)$ in indeed generally non-rational; I didn't claim that it was rational. Note that stability of $\log H(s)$ is implied by assuming that its inverse Fourier transform (the cepstrum) exists. So with stability implied, the locations of the singularities do determine causality. All singularities in the left half-plane means causal, in the right half-plane means anti-causal, and on both sides means two-sided (non-causal). It's generally not true that singularities in the LHP provide for stability, that only holds for *causal* systems.